# c# cassandra DataStax driver version compatibility

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

Is it possible to use Cassandra version 3.6.0 using DataStax c# driver version 3.0.8 ? If so, why do I get the error unconfigured table "table name" error. What other alternatives do I have?

Edit:

I think the issue is I created the table as TableName , however the driver searches for the table tablename (LOWER CASE FOR T and N) and my query is INSERT INTO TableName(Column1) Values(value1)

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you with your error without also seeing your code.  But Luke is right in that it has to be one of those two.

Comment: @Aaron Please see my edit

Comment: Did you create your table name with double quotes?  As in `CREATE TABLE "TableName" (...);`  Because that's the only way Cassandra enforces case on keyspace or table names.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I did so, eg: CREATE TABLE "Keyspace"."TableName" , does that mean I have to recreate the table?

Comment: No, but typically this means that you'll have to include (and escape) the quotes with the table name in the app connection code.

Comment: You don't have to recreate it, but it's probably simpler to just recreate the table/keyspace without the quotes though to avoid case-sensitivity issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use that version of the C# driver against Cassandra 3.6 (or really, any 3.x version). I suspect you're getting the "unconfigured table" error because either:

1. You're not connecting the driver to the keyspace where "table name" has been created.
2. You haven't created the table yet in the keyspace the driver is connecting to.

**Update:** Casing

Sounds like from the comments above you used double quotes when creating tables and the keyspace. My recommendation (if it's feasible) is to just drop and recreate them without the quotes so you don't have to remember to quote everything and use proper case when doing queries. It just tends to be a lot simpler that way. If you want more information on how casing works in CQL, check out the [Uppercase and lowercase section](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html) of the CQL docs.